# How to alter Squarespace Navigation Menu Colors

Tags: css, nav, squarespace

We are building a prototype shop using Squarespace with the four pages:

`Home, Store, About, Contact.`

Unfortunately all pages inherit the same style from the site's design templates.   What we would like to do is something similar to [this](https://answers.squarespace.com/questions/71753/changing-the-color-of-one-navigation-item.html) where the colour of the link on certain pages could be changed.

Is there a method of overcoming the fact that the same class `class="header-nav-item header-nav-item--collection"`is being used for all pages in order for [this type of solution](https://answers.squarespace.com/questions/71753/changing-the-color-of-one-navigation-item.html) using custom CSS can be applied?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do that. Can you provide a link to the site/page in question (and the view-only password, if necessary [such as for trial sites])? Also, do you want a specific link to change based on the page the user is on, or do you want a particular link to always be a different style no matter what page the user is on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Using `nth-child()` selectors is an option, though you might consider referencing the element via its `href` attribute instead, like so (of course, substituting the color of your choice):

```
.header-nav-item a[href='/about'] {
  color: red;
}
```

If you choose to use `nth-child()`, do like so:

```
.header-nav-item:nth-child(3) a {
  color: red;
}
```

Finally, to edit the color of the nav item that corresponds to the active page (whatever page the user is on), you'd write something like:

```
.header-nav-item.header-nav-item--active a {
    color: blue;
}
```

Finally, if you'd like to change the color of all navigation items when the user is on a specific page, you can do so by using the collection ID, which is used as the `id` attribute on the body element in most if not all Squarespace templates:

```
#collection-5d7ef2011673f45f239d1c51 .header-nav-item a {
    color: green;
}
```

As a helpful tip (which you may already be aware of), you can use your [browser's developer tools web inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools#The_Inspector_DOM_explorer_and_CSS_editor) to inspect the element and then write your own CSS according to the rules generated by Squarespace.